# Active Directory - Computer icon with arrow pointing downwards

Tags: icons, active-directory

[image: screenshot of AD showing PC icon with down arrow]

What is the meaning of the PC icon including an arrow pointing downwards?

Answer (score 3):

In short - it means **PC account is disabled.**

> The down arrow on the computer icon in Active Directory Users and
>   Computers indicates that the computer account is currently disabled.
>   Before this computer account can be used, it must be re-enabled.
>   Resetting the account clears the password and allows the account to be
>   used by a new computer. You must rejoin the domain after resetting the
>   account. However, resetting the account will not work in this case
>   until the computer is enabled

Source: https://www.coursehero.com/file/p5qcqv8/Explanation-The-down-arrow-on-the-computer-icon-in-Active-Directory-Users-and/